# Image in bootstrap dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I cant select a dropdown in the dropdown box which has images in them in dropdown how to solve this isue [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqpbb67f/)

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Do you belong to the part of organisation ?</label>  
                <div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
                   <div class="btn-group">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                         <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">
                         Select
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                       </button>

                       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                         <li class="dropdown-header">Select a group </li>
                         <li>
                           <a href="#" title="1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">women entrepreneurship branch</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                           <a href="#" title="1"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">Tamilnadu Corporation for Development of Women</a>
                         </li>
                         <li>
                           <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/50/abstract/">Mompreneur Circle</a>
                         </li>

                       </ul>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You have forgot to add reference to Jquery, Please add a reference to it before adding bootstrap.min.js and check. It seem to work properly.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/3nhs2rxu/ (with jQuery).